# Android ActionBarActivity not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

There should be missing configuration I guess but couldn't find it.
Following my changes for displaying action bar on main activity.

1 - Extend ActionBarActivity for the root activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
```

2 - Updated minsdkversion to 11

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

3 - Add support library android-support-v7-appcombat.jar

4 - Change menu xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_aboutbox"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_aboutbox"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_exit"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_exit"/>

</menu>
```

Following is logcat log after running app.

```
10-17 01:38:18.174: D/AndroidRuntime(1814): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-17 01:38:18.174: D/AndroidRuntime(1814): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 01:38:18.253: D/dalvikvm(1814): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
10-17 01:38:18.274: D/dalvikvm(1814): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
10-17 01:38:18.343: D/dalvikvm(1814): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
10-17 01:38:18.343: D/dalvikvm(1814): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
10-17 01:38:18.504: E/cutils-trace(1814): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-17 01:38:19.464: D/AndroidRuntime(1814): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
10-17 01:38:19.504: D/AndroidRuntime(1814): Shutting down VM
10-17 01:38:19.504: D/dalvikvm(1814): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-17 01:38:20.974: D/AndroidRuntime(1825): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-17 01:38:20.974: D/AndroidRuntime(1825): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 01:38:21.044: D/dalvikvm(1825): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
10-17 01:38:21.075: D/dalvikvm(1825): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
10-17 01:38:21.224: D/dalvikvm(1825): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
10-17 01:38:21.224: D/dalvikvm(1825): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
10-17 01:38:21.364: E/cutils-trace(1825): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-17 01:38:22.224: D/AndroidRuntime(1825): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
10-17 01:38:22.244: D/dalvikvm(1825): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 163 unimplemented (abstract) methods
10-17 01:38:22.284: I/ActivityManager(286): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.siteprice.googlepagerankchecker/.MainActivity} from pid 1825
10-17 01:38:22.314: W/WindowManager(286): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (123x164) to layer 21005
10-17 01:38:22.384: D/AndroidRuntime(1825): Shutting down VM
10-17 01:38:22.384: D/jdwp(1825): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
10-17 01:38:22.384: D/dalvikvm(1825): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-17 01:38:24.334: I/Choreographer(1795): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-17 01:38:24.544: D/dalvikvm(1795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 234K, 11% free 2785K/3100K, paused 42ms, total 80ms
10-17 01:38:25.233: I/Choreographer(1795): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-17 01:38:25.594: I/ActivityManager(286): Displayed org.siteprice.googlepagerankchecker/.MainActivity: +3s246ms
```

Is there anything I should do?

Comment: If supporting API levels lower than 11: use android-support-v7-appcombat.jar
`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` . You don't need to extend `ActionbarActivity` in your case as your min sdk is 11

Comment: I changed android:minSdkVersion="7" and didn't work.

Comment: @Salim pls post the error or elaborate more and how id you add the library project
?

Comment: @Salim Without logcat it would be a bit difficult for anyone to answer your problem. So do post logcat also.

Comment: added logcat main thread.

Comment: by the way I followed instructions on following guide to add support library to my project. http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: So what is the actual problem?

Comment: @Salim So what is the problem or the configuration that you are missing?

Comment: The problem when I run on emulator it doesn't show actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
yourapp:showAsAction="always"
```